# On Leopoldt's conjecture proof

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Mihalescu proved Leopoldt's conjecture between 2008 and 2014.
For example see this http://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7331

Has this been verified and published in a journal?

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps the comments in the discussion [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66252/is-the-leopoldt-conjecture-almost-always-true/68781) on MO from $2011$ give some indication (I suppose you already know this link).

Comment: Often posts to MathOverflow get the response that they are off-topic, and belong on MSE.  This is a rare case of a question that is perhaps more likely to hit an answerer if posted on MathOverflow.

Comment: There has been many different "demonstrations" circulated by Mihailescu, not only of Leopoldt's conjecture (behaviour of p-adic L-functions at s = 1), but also of its "neighbour", the so called Gross-Kuz'min conjecture (s = 0). As far as I know,there has been at least one publication without complete proofs (in the Proc. of the Göttingen NT seminar), and  attempts of publication in international journals which were rejected because of errors or gaps. The last "avatar" was an 1 hour  talk given by the author in 2015 at the Iwasawa conference in London, but I have heard no news since.

Comment: This result is not generally accepted by the alg. number theory community at this time, and my sense is that people don't expect it to be brought to a state where it is actually correct.  (That is, people believe Leopoldt is true, but they don't believe that this gives a correct or near-to-correct proof.)

Comment: See also [this MO-question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99812/status-of-the-leopoldt-conjecture).